# WebMap framework - map+information

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations, content-management-system

I am looking for a kind of Content Management System (CMS) for WebMaps, which already provide components such as a map area, sidebar (description and information), menu, etc.

A list of possible frameworks would be great, just to get an overview of possibilities provided.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good solution called [Bootleaf](https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf) which might get you started.

It provides the framework and page components including the map and side panel. You can easily add Leaflet layers to the map by following the examples given.

[image]

See the live demo at http://bmcbride.github.io/bootleaf/

Comment: Is Bootleaf up to date? I'm asking because Bootleaf states it is based on Bootstrap 3, but Bootstrap has currently version 3.3.7.
Is there any reason to rather make the WebMap based on Bootstrap and Leaflet, than using Bootleaf? Btw, thanks a lot for you last answer!